# How to fix broken UTF-8 string in ruby 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-2.3

I have as an input string tat thinks is UTF-8 but is not and need to fix it. The code is in ruby 2 so iconv is no more and encode or force_encode are not working as intended:

```
[5] pry(main)> a='zg\u0142oszeniem'
=> "zg\\u0142oszeniem"
[6] pry(main)> a.encode("UTF-8", :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => "?")
=> "zg\\u0142oszeniem"
[8] pry(main)> a.encode!(Encoding::UTF_8, :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => "?")
=> "zg\\u0142oszeniem"
[10] pry(main)> a.force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_8)
=> "zg\\u0142oszeniem"
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Single-quoted strings don't process escape sequences (such as `\uXXXX`). Did you mean `"zg\u0142oszeniem"`? This outputs `"zgłoszeniem"`

Comment: So your string contains six literal chars, instead of one unicode codepoint. `["\\", "u", "0", "1", "4", "2"]`

Comment: To give more context: I have a test extending "ActionController::TestCase"  where the broken string is being returned by "response.body". When assertion compares it to sample utf8 string it fails and in output I get the text from the question.

Comment: Well, we need a [mcve] here. Short of you using the wrong quotes (like above), I can't, off the top of my head, tell how a string could "unfold" like this.

Comment: "and need to fix it" - you forgot to define what "fix" means.

Comment: So maybe from other side: My component is being fed by this string and I need to parse it to have propper utf8 chars. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's solution using regex:

`a.gsub(/\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{1,5}|10[0-9a-fA-F]{4})/) { $1.hex.chr(Encoding::UTF_8) }` <sup>1</sup>

It should work for that particular string:

```
[1] pry(main)> before = 'zg\u0142oszeniem'
=> "zg\\u0142oszeniem"
[2] pry(main)> before.split('')
=> ["z", "g", "\\", "u", "0", "1", "4", "2", "o", "s", "z", "e", "n", "i", "e", "m"]
[3] pry(main)> after = before.gsub(/\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{1,5}|10[0-9a-fA-F]{4})/) { $1.hex.chr(Encoding::UTF_8) }
=> "zgłoszeniem"
[4] pry(main)> after.split('')
=> ["z", "g", "ł", "o", "s", "z", "e", "n", "i", "e", "m"]
```

---

[1] Unicode codepoints can range from 0 to 10FFFF<sub>16</sub> ([definition D9 in Section 3.4, Characters and Encoding](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode10.0.0/ch03.pdf#G2212)), that should explains why above regex looks like that.